# How can I edit my Title, Author and Date sections to change the spacing to even them out and shorten the space between, on top and below them?

Tags: spacing, titlesec, author, date

I already have `geometry` set to `top=2cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm`, but I want to make it so that can change the distance between the top of the page and the title, change the space between title, author, and date, and also the space between date and text that gets typed after. The sections are not consistent with the spacing of text on the top of a 2nd page.

Is there a package or something that I would need to install? I have `microtype`, `geometry`, and `fancyhdr`, so I probably am set up with those.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{Times New Roman}[Ligatures=TeX]
    \setmathfont{STIX Two Math}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{Date}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1] \newline

\lipsum[2] \newline

\lipsum[3] \newline

\lipsum[4] \newline

\lipsum[5] \newline

\lipsum[6] \newline

\end{document}
```

Comment: How best to do this depends on your current setup. In particular, your class. You've tagged this `titlesec` but your question doesn't obviously have anything to do with that package which is about formatting the titles of sections, chapters etc. If you mean the document title, `titlesec` won't help. If you are using a standard class and want to format the document title, I generally use `titling`. If you mean the titles of chapters etc., I wouldn't, personally, use `titlesec`, but that's a strictly minority view. An MWE would help. We have no idea what your second page looks like.

Comment: @cfr here's a link to a PDF of what my doc with 2 pages looks like https://jumpshare.com/s/571FFQk29RTB5ZBnn0Ow

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not following a random link from a stranger to view your file. Please provide a minimal working example i.e. code we can compile to reproduce the issue. Seeing your PDF without the code won't help anyway. We'll still need to see the source to help you.

Comment: If you're using a standard class `\@maketitle` and/or `\maketitle` would be the macros where those informations are stored. But as @cfr pointed out, a MWE plus a concrete description/image what you want to achieve would be most helpful.

Comment: @cfr I added code

Comment: @lukeflo yeah im using \maketitle, check my code

Comment: Yes, but in case of `article`, `\maketitle` only typesets the informations. They are formatted with the `\@maketitle` command which is only implicitly called by `\maketitle`. Thus, you have do modify `\@maketitle` to alter the layout.

Comment: @lukeflo I cant find instructions on how to use it. I want to have title be 2cm away from the top of the page, 1.5cm size spaces between the 3 sections, and 2cm space between date and text after \maketitle. GPT-4 didnt help me do this. Can you use my code to help you do what I want?

Comment: What do you mean by "sections"? I don't see any `\section` command in your MWE.

Comment: @lukeflo title, date, and author are what I was referring to as sections.

Comment: Space between title date and author as in between title and author there is 1.5 cm space, and between author and date another 1.5cm

Comment: If you use the `titling` package, you can do what you wish without needing to modify `\@maketitle` directly as it provides hooks for adding code and these can be used to insert the spaces you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code to your preambel:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@maketitle}{%
\newpage
\null
\vskip 2cm%
\begin{center}
\parskip=0pt
\let\footnote\thanks 
{\LARGE \@title \par }%
\vskip 1.5cm%
{\large \lineskip .5em%
\begin{tabular}[t]{c}%
\@author
\end{tabular}%
\par }%
\vskip 1.5cm%
{\large \@date }%
\end{center}\par 
\vskip 2cm%
}
\makeatother
```

This should modify the spaces between the "sections".

Be aware, I couldn't test the code properly since its written on my smartphone. If something went wrong just report here.

Comment: This didn't seem to work, it actually added space to the title author and date parts.

Comment: In the comments your wrote 2, 1.5, 1.5 and 2cm from top to bottom. That are the values I used: "I want to have title be 2cm away from the top of the page, 1.5cm size spaces between the 3 sections, and 2cm space between date and text after \maketitle"